# How to use Amazon EMR–managed security groups using the AWS CLI >=1.11.59?

Tags: emr, aws-cli, amazon-emr

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/ManagementGuide/emr-man-sec-groups.html says in section title "To specify Amazon EMR–managed security groups using the AWS CLI":

> Use the create-cluster command with the
>   --emr-managed-master-security-group and --emr-managed-slave-security-group parameters.

When I run the `aws emr create-cluster` command using these arguments, I get the following error:

```
Unknown options: --emr-managed-master-security-group,--emr-managed-slave-security-group
```

My version of `aws` cli is as follows:

```
$ aws --version
aws-cli/1.11.59 Python/2.7.10 Darwin/16.4.0 botocore/1.5.22
```

What's the new mystical incantation for these unsupported options now?

Update 1: RTFMing via `aws emr create-cluster help` includes the following text:

> ```
>    o Create an Amazon EMR cluster specifying only the  Amazon  EMR-managed
>      Amazon EC2 security groups:
>
>         aws emr create-cluster --release-label emr-5.0.0 --service-role myServiceRole --ec2-attributes InstanceProfile=myRole,EmrManagedMasterSecurityGroup=sg-master1,EmrManagedSlaveSecurityGroup=sg-slave1 --instance-groups InstanceGroupType=MASTER,InstanceCount=1,InstanceType=m3.xlarge InstanceGroupType=CORE,InstanceCount=2,InstanceType=m3.xlarge
> ```

So I think to myself, "Self, I guess you use the literal values 'sg-master1' & 'sg-slave1'", so I update my script & try them, then get an error in the AWS EMR console stating `Terminated with errorsInvalid id: "sg-master1" (Service: AmazonEC2; Status Code: 400; Error Code: InvalidGroupId.Malformed; Request ID: cdd335ba-59f4-407a-b7d6-9cf8a96f08d9)`.  No good; trudging on...

Answer (score 0):

The answer is to place the pre-existing, actual security group ids in the `--ec2-attributes` argument as shown in "Update 1" in my question above.  Also see https://stackoverflow.com/a/42723084/969237.