# What's the aws cli command to create the default EMR-managed security groups?

Tags: emr, aws-cli, amazon-emr, aws-security-group

When using the EMR web console, you can create a cluster and AWS automatically creates the EMR-managed security groups named "ElasticMapReduce-master" & "ElasticMapReduce-slave".  How do you create those via the `aws` cli?

I found `aws emr create-default-roles` but there's no `aws emr create-default-security-groups`.

Answer (score 0):

As of right now, it looks like you can't. See http://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/ManagementGuide/emr-man-sec-groups.html section "To specify Amazon EMR–managed security groups using the AWS CLI":

> Amazon EMR–managed security groups are not supported in the Amazon EMR
>   CLI.

Also see https://github.com/aws/aws-cli/issues/2485